# c# get only child properties without parent class properties

Tags: c#

Is there a way, and not using reflection, of elegant get only child propeties of an object?

For example:

```
class A 
{
    public string PropA;
}

class B : A
{
    public string PropB;
}

class C
{
    var classB_instance = new B();
    /* Only class B properties without parent so B.PropB; but no B.PropA;
}
```

I know it would be possible with reflection, but if this can be avoided?

Comment: Do not inherit `B` from `A`.

Comment: No, not really, unless B implements a specific interface, and you cast it like the interface? Like `ISpecificInterface classB = new B()`

Comment: @Wojciech Szabowicz - Please explain what you are trying to achieve so we can find a proper solution. The simple answer to your question is no but we need more information

Comment: There is no way to hide inherited members, please tell us why you need to do this and we can try coming up with alternative solutions that fit your problem better.

Comment: I have a simple poor man's mapper that sets values from one class to another by checking its property name and  type, thing is in one place if I map some extra fields(here PropA) some values are override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a specific interface for your inherited class like say

```
interface ISpecificB {
    string PropB;
}
```

and then Create your class like

```
public class A {
    public string PropA;
}

public class B: A, ISpecificB {
    public string PropB;
}
```

and only make the variable as specific as `ISpecificB` when creating it or returning it from a function

```
ISpecificB classB = new B();

classB.PropA // shouldn't be available
```

However, classB could still be casted as B or A which would give access to the propA and it might increase complexity in your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `protected` accessibility modifier:

> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

```
public class A 
{
    protected string PropA { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    var classB_instance = new B();
    //You can't access classB_instance.PropA
}
```

Comment: Also not with a specific interface as I added in my comment above? I mean there are some workarounds, though your point is perfectly valid as well :)

Comment: @Icepickle - You are correct with the casting and am rethinking my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could mark PropA as private, look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx:

> private
>      The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

just a short note: most of the time, I use reflection to do exactly the opposite: access things I am not allowed, for example, because they are private... ;-) reflection is not a "tool" to hide something, AFAIK. it opens every door which is usually locked ;-)

Comment: that's not part of the original question... ;-)

Comment: Using reflection to do the things you do in most cases indicates of a problem with the design....

Comment: I did not say "I use reflection to design my solution". sometimes, reflection is the answer, like attribute access, right?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can do this way ?

```
class A 
{
   private string PropA; 
}

class B : A
{
 public string PropB;
}
class C
{
  var classB_instance = new B();     
}
```